# Rearranging equation

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

I want to rearrange an equation of the form

```
a*f'[x] + b*f[x] +g[x]+h[x]==0
```

into

```
a*f'[x]+b*f[x] == - g[x] - h[x]
```

I've tried using rules but I can't arrive to something working correctly...

Answer (score 3):

march's answer is  correct but perhaps one could do this in stages to make the generality of the method for transforming algebraic equations more transparent. First step is the same:

```
eqn = a*f'[x] + b*f[x] + g[x] + h[x] == 0
```

Then use the pure function and slot to do the first algebraic step of subtracting g[x] from both sides:

```
eqn1 = # - g[x] & /@ eqn
```

Repeat for the second function:

```
eqn2 = # - h[x] & /@ eqn1

(* a f'(x)+b f(x)=-g(x)-h(x) *)
```

This produces the result and these transformations can be used to perform operations on equations that follow textbooks etc. Sorry if this is overly simplistic.

Answer (score 2):

```
eqn = a*f'[x] + b*f[x] + g[x] + h[x] == 0;
# - Select[eqn[[1]], ! FreeQ[#, g | h] &] & /@ eqn
(* b f[x] + a f'[x] == -g[x] - h[x] *)
```